# DataView and ASP.Net: Joining Table and adding data to a List object?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dataview

I'm learning the ropes of ASP.Net and I'm trying to figure out how to properly join two SQL data tables (one for Questions, the other for Answers, I've made the id for the question a foreign key in the answer table - the primary key on both tables is 'Id', while the foreign key on the Answers table related to the question table is called 'QuestionID') in ASP and then place that data into a list (and eventually a Question class, but that's not what I'm getting caught on).

I'm trying to use DataView and I think (hope) I'm on a right track but my SQL is foggy at best and I'm not quite sure now (or even if I should) join the two tables.

Would I be better off trying to fiddle around with two SqlDataSources? It seems like redundancy to me when I have a link between the tables. If I was to boil down my problem it's I'm not sure how to navigate the DataView in C# or how to set up my ASP parameters.

I've enclosed my ASP control(s) and my C# below - any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

ASP:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldataQuestions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Questions] WHERE ([Id] = @Id)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Id" Type="Int32"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldataAnswers" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Answers] WHERE ([QuestionID] = @QuestionID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#

```
        try
        {
            DataView dvQuestions = (DataView)sqldataQuestions.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
            DataView dvAnswers = (DataView)sqldataAnswers.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

            int count = 0;
            List<String> questionList = new List<string>();
            List<String> answerList = new List<string>();

            while (dvQuestions[count]["QuestionText"].ToString() != null)
            {
                questionList.Add(dvQuestions[count]["QuestionText"].ToString());

                while (dvAnswers[count]["AnswerText"].ToString() != null) // This is where I totally fall apart, trying to pull the related Answers to the current question.
                {

                }

                count++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                   
            Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a single datasource and amend the SQL to bring back the joined data required:

```
SELECT q.*, a.* FROM Questions  q 
INNER JOIN Answers  a ON a.QuestionId = q.ID
```